# Pattern Matching to check if string is null or empty

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Is it possible to check if string is null or empty using match?

I'm trying to do something like:

```
def sendToYahoo(message:Email) ={
  val clientConfiguration = new ClientService().getClientConfiguration()
  val messageId : Seq[Char] = message.identifier
  messageId match {
    case messageId.isEmpty => validate()
    case !messageId.isEmpty => //blabla
  }
}
```

But i have a compile error.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can write a simple function like:

```
def isEmpty(x: String) = Option(x).forall(_.isEmpty)
```

or

```
def isEmpty(x: String) = x == null || x.isEmpty
```

You might also want to trim the string, if you consider `"    "` to be empty as well.

```
def isEmpty(x: String) = x == null || x.trim.isEmpty
```

and then use it

```
val messageId = message.identifier
messageId match {
  case id if isEmpty(id) => validate()
  case id => // blabla
}
```

or without a `match`

```
if (isEmpty(messageId)) {
  validate()
} else {
  // blabla
}
```

or even

```
object EmptyString {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[String] =
    if (s == null || s.trim.isEmpty) Some(s) else None
}

message.identifier match {
  case EmptyString(s) => validate()
  case _ => // blabla
}
```

Comment: Good idea with the trimming! It's so often forgotten.

Comment: `not . exists == forall`

Comment: shouldn't it be this?
def isEmpty(x: String) = x == null || Option(x.trim).forall(_.isEmpty)

Comment: @sowen woops, yes, there was a mistake on the logic condition, thanks. I've updated my solution

Comment: would add the type option on the public member: `def isEmpty(x: String): Boolean = Option(x).forall(_.isEmpty)`

Answer (score 13):

```
def isNullOrEmpty[T](s: Seq[T]) = s match {
     case null => true
     case Seq() => true
     case _ => false
}
```

Comment: the Scala language designers would have made our scala nubies lifes much more easier by providing an isNullable trait with the isNull method like:

  def isNull[T](obj: T) = obj match {
    case null => true
    case _ => false
  }

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to check whether a String is null or empty, here's a one-liner that does that. You wrap it with an Option, use filter to make sure it's not an empty String then call getOrElse to provide a default value in case the original value is either null or an empty String.

```
Option(s).filter(!_.isEmpty).getOrElse(columnName)
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.